# Google Earth Engine: Error generating chart: Data column(s) for axis #0 cannot be of type string

Tags: javascript

Estoy tratando de graficar una serie de tiempo de índices climáticos obtenidos a partir del producto Gridmet Drought, pero me sale el siguiente error: Error generating chart: Data column(s) for axis #0 cannot be of type string.

Este es mi script:

```
// cargo dataset
var GRIDMET = ee.ImageCollection("GRIDMET/DROUGHT")
.filter(ee.Filter.date('2010-02-18', '2022-06-26'))
.filterBounds(PNI)
.select('spi30d','eddi30d','spei30d','pdsi','z');

print(GRIDMET);

var GRIDMET_2 = GRIDMET.map(function(image) {
  return image.set('timeFormat', image.date().format('dd-MM-yyyy'))});
  
print(GRIDMET_2);

// Crear gráfico serie de tiempo SPI
var SPI = ui.Chart.image.seriesByRegion(
GRIDMET_2, PNI.geometry().bounds(), ee.Reducer.mean(), 'spi30d', 1000, 'timeFormat', 'label')
  .setChartType('ScatterChart')
  .setOptions({
    title: 'SPI a través del tiempo',
    hAxis: { title: 'Tiempo'},
    vAxis: {title: 'SPI'},
    lineWidth: 1});
   
print(SPI)
```